# Оптимизировать задачу factorial

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int number;
int x = 1;

scanf("%d", &number);

if ( number < 0 ) {
    printf("-1\n");
} else {
    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++ ) {
        x *= ( i + 1 );
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

return 0;    
}
```

Вариант №2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n) {

if ( n < 0 ) {
    return -1;
}
if ( n <= 1 ) {
    return 1;
}
return n * factorial(n-1);
}

int main() {
int m;

scanf("%d", &m);
printf("%d\n", factorial(m));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переписать вариант 1 так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int number, x = 1;

  scanf("%d", &number);

  if ( number < 0 ) x = -1;
  else {
    for ( ; number > 1; number-- ) x *= number;
  }
  printf("%d\n", x);

  return 0;    
}
```

Но это не особо то и оптимизация.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!)

Answer (score 4):

Вычисление факториала по модулю **p** за время **O(p LOG N)**, где **LOG** по основанию **p**. (p - простое)

```
    int res = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        res = (res * ((n/p) % 2 ? p-1 : 1)) % p;
        for (int i=2; i<=n%p; ++i)
            res = (res * i) % p;
        n /= p;
    }
    return res % p;
```

Подробное описание [тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/modular_factorial).

**А вот и оптимизация по коду:**

```
long f(long a) {return (a>1?a*f(a-1):1);}

Тогда f(x) = x!
```

Comment: А можно советы по моему коду?))

Comment: Ваше решение "в лоб": как есть, так и вычислем.
<br />
Чтобы ускорить вычисление необходимо использовать другие методы. Факториал - функция, которая очень быстро растёт, поэтому целесообразно считать факториал по модулю, как в моём ответе.

Comment: Спасибо я это понимаю, но задача была поставлена так,и нужно оптимизировать этот код(

Comment: Оптимизация по размеру кода?